# Three tables and get fields joined with intermediary field

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables T1, T2, and T3 with hte following columns.

```
T1: a, b
T2 b, c
T3 c,d
```

I want to create a view called T4 with fields a,d

How do I write a query to do this?

Comment: You mean something like.. `CREATE VIEW T4 AS SELECT a, d FROM T1, T3`?

Comment: Please don't go away after asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join them like this:

```
CREATE VIEW T4 AS 
SELECT T1.a, T3.d
FROM T1 
JOIN T2 ON T1.b = T2.b
JOIN T3 ON T2.c = T3.c
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b550f/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
CREATE VIEW T4
AS
SELECT 
T1.a, 
T3.d
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.b = T2.b
INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.c = T3.c
```